# User profile editing in drupal

Tags: drupal-6

1.) I had an implementation for user registration for which I needed to make two extra tables and used "users" table as well(I've made a custom module for this purpose). I've collected the information while user is registering and put them in appropriate tables. Now I need to provide user with an interface where he can update his profile(this includes tables which I mentioned above).

2.) Further more, I need to make filters that admin can see the list of users e.g. who have salary more than $10,000. I need to provide two predefined filters and facility to make more filters for admin.

How can I do both of the above question? is there any module?

Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

1) You could use [hook_user](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_user/6) "form" operation to add fields to the user account edit form. You could then use the "submit" operation to write any changes to the database.

2) I recommend using the [Table Wizard module](https://drupal.org/project/tw) to expose the data to Views. Then use Views to do the reporting. That would give you the ability to easily add more filters later, as needed.

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for you reply. talking about 2), I am not able to get fields in views, may be I am not getting it right. I've 4 tables, Users(default of drupal), user_extra_info, club_user, and user_select_brands... I need information from both 4 tables in a single view. I've tried making relationship from table wizard but i think I am not getting it correct. can you help?

Comment: Also I am new to drupal and don't get idea about relationships in views

Comment: Relationships in views are used to join multiple tables. You'll need to be more specific about where you're stuck, what you tried, what you're seeing, what you expect to see, etc., in order for me to help.